# Appending line to a existing file having extra new line in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file

```
apple
banana
```

Now you watch closely there is blank line at the end.

When in do append

```
f = open("file.txt",'a')
f.write("orange")
f.close()
```

I get output:

```
apple
banana

orange
```

I want to remove the blank line in between during appends.

I know i can do that manually going to the file and removing the extra new line. But i want to do it in python. So every time the blank line is there its gets removed automatically like this:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

I search and experimented but no avail

Comment: How is the blank line getting there in the first place, if you are appending to this file?

Comment: Michael is right-  the simplest way to deal with the new line is to keep it from ever being written.

Comment: @Michael: Its config file which you sometimes edit manually and by mistake you leave one or two blank lines. Actually its used my multiple users and will edit it. Anyway it was just my curiosity how can i do it ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because, well, append mode does exactly that: It appends. To the newline. You will have to read in the file, remove the newline at the end, write it out and then append.

Or, open the file for reading and writing (mode `'r+'`), seek to the end, remove the newline, and then continue with writing.

I think this could do the trick:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r+')
f.seek(-2, 2) # last character in file
if f.read(2) == '\n\n':
   f.seek(-1, 1) # wow, we really did find a newline! rewind again!
f.write('orange')
f.close()
```

Comment: We only need to strip newline characters if there are *multiple* newlines at the end of the file.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think `f.seek(-1)` works.  You would need `f.seek(-1, 2)` for the first call and `f.seek(-1, 1)` for the second one.

Answer (score 14):

use:

```
f = open("file.txt",'ab')
```

'ab' instead of only 'a'

Comment: 'ab' means "append, binary". The file.txt was not binary, based on the question by OP.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to overwrite the whole file instead of modifying it in place:

```
with open("file.txt") as input:
    # Read non-empty lines from input file
    lines = [line for line in input if line.strip()]
with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in lines:
        output.write(line)
    output.write("orange\n")
```

This code will work fine as long as the file is not too large.

You could do this more efficiently by opening the file for reading and writing, finding the number of newline characters at the end of the file, seeking to the position after the first trailing newline character and writing the line to append there.  This is more efficient, but also requires more elaborate code, so I'd only do this if the simple solution isn't fast enough.

**Edit**: Here's my take on the more efficient way of doing this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+U") as f:
    try:
        f.seek(-1, 2)
        while f.read(1) == "\n":
            f.seek(-2, 1)      # go back two characters, since
                               # reading advances by one character
    except IOError:            # seek failed, so the file consists
        f.seek(0)              # exclusively of newline characters
    else:
        f.write("\n")          # Add exactly one newline character
    f.write("orange\n")        # Add a new line
```

This works correctly for any number of trailing newline characters, including none at all or more than two.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that works with the file in place:

```
with open('fruit.txt','rU+') as f:
    f.seek(-2,2)
    if(f.read(2) == "\n\n"):
        f.seek(-1,2)
    f.write('strawberry\n')
```

We open the file for reading and writing (`'r+'`).  Then we seek to 2 bytes from the end.  We read those bytes.  (the file pointer is not at the end of the file).  If those bytes are both newlines, we step back one byte.  Then we write our new data.

**EDIT** In a more general case:

```
def goto_my_eof(f):
    """Position file pointer after last newline in file
       raises IOError if the file is "empty" (has no contents or only whitespace)
    """
    n=-1
    f.seek(n,2)
    mychar=f.read(1)
    #Step backward, one character at a time, looking for non-whitespace
    while not (mychar.strip()): 
        n-=1
        f.seek(n,2)
    mychar=f.read(1)
    #seek to the position after the non-whitespace position
    f.seek(n+1,2)
    #write one newline and continue.
    f.write('\n')
```

Seems to work (after a little experimenting).  Also, this will strip off any whitespace (not just newlines).  Some combination of this and the answer by @SvenMarnach (who more elegantly used `try` and `except` to catch errors) would be great.  In the case of my function, you could enclose it in a `try`/`except` and seek to position 0 if `except IOError` occurs (since the function assumes there is some non-whitespace text in the file).

Answer (score 0):

I would write this code to add a new line to a file:

```
f=open('newfile.txt','a')

t=raw_input('write here something you like: ')

f.write(t+'\n')
```

and then to read what is there in the file, fire up the shell and type:

```
with open('newfile.txt','a') as f:
   for l in f:
       print l
```

This will print everything from the file.

I hope it answers your question!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way out. Write a string in raw format and do not include new space.

```
 f=open('newfile.txt','a') 
 f.write(f"{your_string}")
```

That is it.
No new line in the file.